# Component based entity system in scala

Tags: scala, architecture, game-engine, roguelike, component-based

I'm searching some library which implement the [Component Based Entity System (ECS)](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013) framework used in multiple game and implementend in many game engine (unity, libgdx, etc.)

I'm starting a little game project in scala ( [ECS roguelike](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Entity_Component_System)), and at this time i only find a java library named [ashley](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki).

Do you know if other ECS libraries (in Scala) exists, or if the only way is to use or reimplement this library in scala (ashley) ?

Another related question, the Actor paradigm and Component Based Entity System is not so distant, what is the difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the question about differences with an Actor system, the purpose of an Actor system is to allow asynchronous communication between actors. i don't see anything in ECS which is related to asynchronicity. In fact, from one of your links:

> Each system will be updated once per frame in a logical order

This implies synchronous, blocking progress through the program, so quite different from an actor system where the components would be sending each other messages in a concurrent fashion.

Regarding your need for an ECS library in Scala. Scala and Java are interoperable, is there any reason you can't simply use `ashley` within your scala code?

Comment: Because i love scala ? :) 
Now i want to use scala.js / scala for this game, so if i can avoid java, it's better. Perhaps a redevelopment of Ashley is possible "in not so many time ?" I study the question...